# How are sleeping threads woken, at the lowest level?

Tags: events, operating-system, message-queue, thread-sleep

I've wondered about this for a very long time.

I understand that GUI programming is event-driven. I understand that most GUI programms will feature an event loop which loops through all events on the message queue. I also understand that it does so by calling some kind of Operating System method like "get_message()", which will block the thread until a message is received. In this sense, when no events are happening, the thread is sleeping peacefully.

My question, however, is: how does the Operating System check for available messages?Somewhere down the stack I assume there must be a loop which is continually checking for new events. Such a loop cannot possibly feature any blocking, because if so, there must be another looping thread which is 'always-awake', ready to wake the first. However, I also appreciate that this cannot be true, because otherwise I would expect to see 100% of at least one processor core in use at all times, checking over and over and over and over....

I have considered that perhaps the checking thread has a small sleep between each iteration. This would certainly explain why an idle system isn't using 100% CPU. But then I recalled how events are usually responded to immediately. Take a mouse movement for example: the cursor is being constantly redrawn, in sync with the physical movements.

Is there something fundamental, perhaps, in CPU architectures that allows threads to be woken at the hardware level, when certain memory addresses change value?

I'm otherwise out of ideas! Could anyone please help to explain what's really happening?

Comment: Yes there is: hardware interrupts. A gross oversimplification: when a key is pressed or the mouse is moved, the OS handles the interrupt, and checks if there are sleeping threads that are 'IO blocked' - waiting for input - and then wakes them up. Such sleeping threads make a kernel call _like_ your `get_message`, and if there isn't any data available, the thread won't be scheduled to run, until there is data available.

Comment: Thanks, Kenney. The very statement that there is hardware involvement has answered my question. If anyone would like to write this as a formal answer, I'll happily accept it. Exactly how such hardware interrupts impact the low-level software is, I guess, a much greater can of worms that I won't dare open here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is: hardware interrupts.

When a key is pressed or the mouse is moved, or a network packet arrives, or data is read from some other device, or a timer elapses, the OS receives a hardware interrupt.

Threads or applications wanting to do I/O have to call a function in the OS, which returns the requested data, **or**, suspends the calling thread if the data is not available yet. This suspension simply means the thread is not considered for scheduling, until some condition changes - in this case, the requested data must be available. Such threads are said to be 'IO blocked'.

When the OS receives an interrupt indicating some device has some data, it looks through it's list of suspended threads to see if there is one that is suspended because it is waiting for that data, and then removes the suspension,
making it eligible for scheduling again.

In this interrupt-driven way, no CPU time is wasted 'polling' for data.